# How to execute two exactly same maven profiles with a different system property value?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-2, maven-3

I have the below-mentioned implementation in my `pom` file

```
<profile>
        <id>test</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            <property>
                <name>test</name>
            </property>
        </activation>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>transform</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformationSets>
                            <transformationSet>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>set.xml</include>
                                </includes>
                                <dir>test/resources/</dir>
                                <stylesheet>
                                    test/resources/ser.xsl
                                </stylesheet>
                                <outputDir>test/resources</outputDir>
                            </transformationSet>
                        </transformationSets>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
                            <artifactId>saxon</artifactId>
                            <version>8.7</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.22.1</version>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <configuration>
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>maven.test.haltafterfailure</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>java.io.tmpdir</name>
                                <value>${basedir}/target/</value>
                            </property>
                            <property>
                                <name>isValid</name>
                                <value>false</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

I want this profile to execute again with the system property `isValid` is `true`
When I replicate this profile config and added it again with `isValid` equals `true` the first profile config is getting overridden.

***From Maven documentation...***

*This profile will automatically be active for all builds unless another profile in the same POM is activated using one of the previously described methods. All profiles that are active by default are automatically deactivated when a profile in the pom is activated on the command line or through its activation config. ...*

I tried to add two executions as below:

```
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>transform</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>.... </configuration>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>transform</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>.... </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
```

But I don't know how to set the system variables and `<suiteXmlFile>` property inside `<execution>` with **xml-maven-plugin**

What plugin do I need to use to achieve my requirement?

Is there a way to run these 2 profiles with the system property isValid equals to `true` and `false` and with different `<suiteXmlFile>` values(different testng files) at once?

Answer (score 2):

If you replicate the profile, then you define the same plugin twice and so the configuration is overridden.

Instead, define two `<executions>` of the same plugin.

Comment: How can we specify  `<system variables>` and   `<suiteXmlFile>`  inside  `<executions>` . I think they are not allowed inside `<executions>`

Comment: Have you tried it? I would put it into the `<configuration>` block inside the `<execution>`.

Comment: We can specify  `<configuration>` in to `<execution>` . But, As I am using ` xml-maven-plugin` it is not allowing me to put `<systemVariables>`.

Comment: Yes, but in your solution, this is also the case. And furthermore, for what do you need a system variable in the xml maven plugin?

Comment: I need tests to be run twice. In first run it should run with `isValid=true` and then `isValid=false`. If we can't specify it in xml maven plugin how can we do this ?

Comment: Depends on what you do in the xml maven plugin.